# CosmosDB Ladder pattern

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm reading this documentation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/03/15/going-social-with-documentdb/ … it talks about a “Ladder pattern” but there are no examples and I can't seem to find this anywhere else. Could I get a little more direction on this concept?
I want to update all data duplicates with a pattern so i can update the main records and don't need to worry about it updating it everywhere its duplicated or reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at old documentation,

check the updated one on **[`The “Ladder” pattern and data duplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/social-media-apps#the-ladder-pattern-and-data-duplication)**

Let’s take user information as an example:

```
{
    "id":"dse4-qwe2-ert4-aad2",
    "name":"John",
    "surname":"Doe",
    "address":"742 Evergreen Terrace",
    "birthday":"1983-05-07",
    "email":"john@doe.com",
    "twitterHandle":"@john",
    "username":"johndoe",
    "password":"some_encrypted_phrase",
    "totalPoints":100,
    "totalPosts":24
}
```

By looking at this information, we can quickly detect which is critical information and which isn’t, thus creating a “Ladder”: